# How to increase the clickable area of a nested clickable Text

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

How to increase the clickable area of a nested text component in react-native? I can create a nested hyperlink like this:

```
<Text>Please click <Text onPress={doSomething}>here</Text> to read more</Text>
```

However, the clickable area of this hyperlink is tiny, which leads to bad UX. The user has to spam the area to fire this hyperlink. Any suggestions?

You can also check out this snack sample (which shows the desired behaviour on web and doesn't work on android): https://snack.expo.io/iL8MujO1F

Comment: Add padding to the Clickable element.

Comment: I tried that, this doesn't work

Comment: Try posting your minimum reproducible code using https://snack.expo.io/

Comment: I updated the question with a snack example

Comment: Hi there, added an answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

What you are dealing with is `Text` elements inside of `Text` elements which is not very flexible in Android.

So one way to achieve this is to make the full line around the highlighted text as clickable.

This makes your code like this,

```
<Text onPress={() => alert('Hit')}>
    I can create a nested hyperlink like{' '}
    <Text style={{ color: 'blue' }}>this</Text>. However, the clickable
    area of this hyperlink is tiny, which leads to bad UX.
</Text>
```

Here is an [updated snack](https://snack.expo.io/@nisanth-reddy/shallow-watermelon). Check it out.

Comment: Thanks, but this works only on web, not on android or ios. I added backgroundcolor to visualize the clickable area: https://snack.expo.io/_UT3JrZcF

Comment: Ah, understood. i'll try to fix this. But as far as I now. Android doesn't support having absolutely positioned inline text elements. One hack would be to make your entire line clickable, but change color of the actual text only.

Comment: I guess this would work for me too, could you send another snack maybe?

Comment: @JohnDoe I have updated my answer check it out.

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I missunderstood. I have one long article (parent text element) which has multiple links nested inside, so in these cases it wouldn't work..

Comment: if you know the text before hand, you could still break it into chunks.

Comment: Thanks, but it's till too hacky, especially when hyperlinks are close too each other (and on different smartphones the line breaks can occur on different places), this could lead to odd UX.

Comment: Agreed. No solution can solve multiple hyperlinks in a para problem without manipulating the text. Increasing the text size comes close but again empty spaces start occuring